# SWIFT first steps

Tags: swift

I have a class `Master` which represents a player in my game.

I need to add a computed property isAlive to my `Master` object based on the player's life points which lets me tell if the player is dead or alive.

I also need array with 10 players with different amounts of hp (life) points.

Next I need to filter the array to only players that are still alive, and the last step is map the resulting array and display this table as a list.

```
Import Foundation


class Master {
let playerName : String = ""
let hp : Int = 0
 var isAlive : Bool {
 get{ return hp >0 
 }
 }
let avatar : String? = nil
init (playerName: String, hp: Int, isAlive: Bool, avatar: String? = nil ) {
    self.playerName = playerName
    self.hp = hp
    self.isAlive = isAlive
    self.avatar = avatar
 }
extension Master: CustomStringConvertible {
var description: String() {
    if(avatar.isEmpty){
        return name + " - (" + isAlive + " / " + hp + ") - Nie posada 
    awatara"
    }else{
        return name + " - (" + isAlive + " / " + hp + ") - Posiada awatar"
    }
}

}

}
class MasterViewController: UIViewController {

var masters = [Master]()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    (0..<10).forEach { masters.append(Master(playerName: "q"+$0, hp: 12 + 
  $0, 
 avatar: nil)
  (playerName: "w"+$1, hp: 12 + 
  $1, 
 avatar: nil)
  (playerName: "e"+$2, hp: 12 + 
  $2, 
 avatar: nil)
 (playerName: "qw"+$3, hp: 12 + 
  $3, 
 avatar: nil)
 (playerName: "we"+$4, hp: 12 + 
  $4, 
 avatar: nil)
 (playerName: "2"+$5, hp: 12 + 
  $5, 
 avatar: nil))} 


    let aliveMasters = masters.filter { $0.isAlive }


    let mappedMasters: [String] = masters.map { $0.playerName }
    print("Alive Masters are : \(mappedMasters)")

 }
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! The question need some more details, please elaborate more.  
Also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `import CustomStringConvertible` ??  CustomStringConvertible it is not a framework. There is nothing to import. You just need to implement the description property in your class or struct to conform to it.

Comment: You need to move your extension out of your Master class declaration brackets

Comment: You've stated a set of objectives, but haven't asked a question. What part of your goal do you need help with, and what have you tried? You said you need to make isAlive a computed property, but you have made it a normal `Bool` property. Do you need help understanding how to create a computed property?

Comment: You probably want to make the `hp` property of your `Master` object a `var` rather than a `let` constant. Otherwise you won't be able to change the amount of life points a player has left as they take damage.

Answer (score 1):

Computed property is simply a way to control the way a property is accessed, you can change :

```
let isAlive : Bool
```

to :

```
var isAlive: Bool {
    get {
        return hp > 0
    }
}
```

**Also remove all isAlive steps reference from init(_:), just keep the computed property.**

Then, from another view controller using your Model :

```
class MasterViewController: UIViewController {

    var masters = [Master]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add array with 10 players with hp points
        masters.append(Master(playerName: "John Doe", hp: 100, avatar: nil))
        masters.append(Master(playerName: "Jack Jones", hp: 50, avatar: nil))
        masters.append(Master(playerName: "Susan Scott", hp: 150, avatar: nil))
        // Add any masters here ...
        // Another way of doing it : (0..<10).forEach { masters.append(Master(playerName: ""+$0, hp: 12 + $0, avatar: nil)) }

        // filter array to return alive players
        let aliveMasters = masters.filter { $0.isAlive }

        // map the resulenter code hereting array and display this table as a list.
        // Here aliveMasters is already an array of Masters, map is used to "transform" data
        let mappedMasters: [String] = masters.map { $0.playerName }
        print("Alive Masters are : \(mappedMasters)")

    }

}
```

Comment: Except with isAlive a computed property, the initializer would not take an isAlive parameter, so you'd need to refactor the code that creates `Master` objects so you're not passing a value in for the `isAlive` property.

Comment: I try add this to my code but always error. I don't know why.  3 h job and i can't.

Comment: to start with you need to change most of your properties from being "let" to being "var". let is a constant, once you set it, you can't change it again. for example you have hitpoints as let hp = 0. this means that hp will always be zero and you won't be able to change its value

Comment: Thank you so much Guys Now What i must change ?

Comment: Probably i added all

Comment: Just edited my answer so you can add your players easily to the array. Please mark the answer as resolved if it solved your issue.